# How do I know when all controls have loaded and displayed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What is the real order of events in a Windows Forms application?

What I mean is, when I put code in the `Form_Shown` event, I expect that code only to run after the form has been *Shown*:

> verb (used with object), showed, shown or showed, showing. 1. to cause
>   or allow to be seen... - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shown

But the `Form_Shown` event is a little misleading. If I do some heavy stuff inside that event, it seems as though the code gets executed *before* the `Form` has *finished* been shown. Let's say that I have a `MainMenu`, a small `Toolbar` and a `TextBox` on a form.

I want to do some heavy stuff (nevermind threads and workers for now...), so the last event I can use I would think would be `Form_Shown`. So I put my heavy code in there, but when the Form begins to display, I end up waiting ~ 5 - 6 seconds for the `Toolbar` and stuff to display (which ends up happening *after* my heavy code does its thing.

Which leads me to believe that I'm subscribing to the wrong event. I don't want the `Form_Shown` event at all. What I really need is:

`Form_WhenALLTheThingsHaveShownEventHandler` event.

So, how can I know _when all the things (controls) have been fully loaded and displayed?

Comment: If you're doing heavy stuff (for 5-6 seconds!), the UI will freeze (and not repaint) for that long no matter which event you put it in. If it really takes that long, you should really look into a backgroundworker or thread (I know, you said nevermind that, but still)

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah. I already have the BackgroundWorker events (albeit empty right now) added. I just got a little distracted and went searching and couldn't find anything on this. And now it's bugging me that I don't know how to tell when all the things have displayed. I'm sure it'll come in handy one day...

Comment: Can you not use the `Form.Load` handler to do the "heavy" code before the form is shown?

Comment: You need to use a background thread to perform hard work. Execution of heavy and prolonged operation in main UI stream anyway freeze the form. Even if the menu and toolbar are created and shown to the user, they will not work until the work is completed.

Answer (score 3):

The `Shown` event is in fact the last event related to initialization that is raised. However, note that the actual *rendering* (drawing on-screen) of UI objects in Windows (and on other platforms) is deferred. The creation of a UI object merely allocates all the necessary resources and "invalidates" the visual area of the object. The platform then later schedules the rendering event (in unmanaged Windows, this is `WM_PAINT`, in the Winforms API this would be the `Paint` event for a `Control` instance).

The rendering event cannot be dispatched until the UI object's thread is available, and if you have long-running code in the `Shown` event, that will keep the UI object's thread unavailable for the duration of your code. I.e. nothing gets drawn until your code completes.

There are other events that you could use to more reliably detect when things have "settled down". For example, the [`Application.Idle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle(v=vs.110).aspx) event tells you when the main application thread is about to enter the idle state. Alternatively, you could just subscribe to the form's [`Paint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) event. In either case, you would want to use [`BeginInvoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) to dispatch your long-running code, so that you don't block the handling of *those* events.

Now, all that said: you really should not be performing any long-running work in the UI thread, period. Using either of the above events doesn't solve the underlying problem; it simply delays the problem until after the initial rendering of your UI. The UI will still remain blocked while your long-running work is executing, and frankly the user may actually find it preferable for there to be no UI at all, than for there to be something that looks like they can interact with but which they can't (i.e. is unresponsive to their input).

In the latest version of .NET, there are some very nice mechanisms available for shifting long-running work to background threads, so that the UI can remain responsive. See [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) and [the `async` and `await` keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) in C#. You could instead use the older `BackgroundWorker` object to accomplish the same, if you prefer.